# How to use the same code for multiple pages?

Tags: pages, wp-admin

The code below prevents a page (defined by its title) from being deleted.

When I try to implement two occurrences of this code (one for each page I want to prevent from being deleted) I receive the white screen of death.

How would I list more than one page by title and prevent both from being deleted?

```
add_action( 'wp_trash_post', 'stop_deleting');
function stop_deleting($page){
    $page = get_page_by_title( 'About' );
        if ($page)
            die('You are not allowed to delete this page');
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Please **show** us your actual code, and don't just describe what you implemented. In this particular case, it is vital to see **how** you tried to implement *two occurrences* of the code.

Anyway, from what I understand, the following function should do what you've asked for:

```
add_action('wp_trash_post', 'wpse_136052_do_not_delete');
function wpse_136052_do_not_delete($id) {
    if (in_array(get_post($id), array(
        get_page_by_title('About'),
        get_page_by_title('Other Page'),
        get_page_by_title('Third Page'),
    )))
        die('You are not allowed to delete this page');
} // function wpse_136052_do_not_delete
```

Comment: Two occurrences means the same code with a different page assigned, it would have been redundant to post both.

The code you provided does not work. Unlike the code provided in the question, it does not prevent deletion.

Comment: Sorry, I forgot to adjust the function name in the `add_action` call. I just updated the code. And regarding your comment and the _white screen of death_: you cannot use multiple functions with the same name. You would have to call the functions `stop_deleting_1` and `stop_deleting_2` or something like that, but that is **not** efficient. You really should bundle this into a single function (as you've asked for, and as I've provided).

Comment: Oh, and BTW, the code in your question does not work (as expected). Yes, it prevents the page with title 'About' from being deleted - but also every other page, as long as the About page does exist.